# Hex Values in Square Brackets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing a program that lets users know if translated strings will fit into an interface. Some characters are represented by a two-digit hex value surrounded by square brackets, such as [C0]. They do not follow standard ASCII or Unicode values. Strings are read from a rich text box, but the bracketed hex values are always replaced when I try and parse them.

How can I keep the text value in a rich text box from losing the bracketed hex values?

Rich text box text:
"Voc[c4] ganhou!"

Then in the program I do this:
string plainLine = richTextBox1.Text;

then plainLine has the value: "Voc¬ ganhou!"

Comment: It is very hard to see why it happens without small code sample... Please consider adding one to the post.

Comment: If the Rich Text Box contains the text: "Voc[c4] ganhou!" and in the code I do this:       string plainLine = richTextBox1.Text; The value stored in plainLine looks like this: "Voc¬ ganhou!" I want to keep the [c4] in the string.